# Access-SQL First Difference

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

What would be the easiest way to construct a first-difference table for a given date. E.g.:

```
Date      | IDPosition | Quantity | Price | TotalPrice
14.04.16  | 1          | 1500     | 10    | 15000
15.04.16  | 1          | 2500     | 15    | 37500
----------------------------------------------------------
Diff      | 1          | 1000     | 5     | 22500
```

Edit:

Got it

```
SELECT (t1.Quantity - t2.Quantity) as QDiff
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
on t1.IDPosition = t2.IDPosition
where t2.Date = DateAdd('d', -1, t1.Date);
```

Comment: Please define "first-difference". However, this looks like a task for a spreadsheet.

Comment: The first-difference ist the difference between two consecutive positions in time with regard to some arbitrary metric e.g. Quantity or Price. It describes the change from one period to the next. See: http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411diff.htm

Comment: OK. And you have only two records?

Comment: No i have a table with several thousand records. The table was just an example to show the general structure.

Comment: Well, but for many records, what output do you expect?

Comment: Several thousand. The solution i posted above works for me so this question can be closed.

Comment: Oh, great, but that was quite different from your original question. As everything is sorted out, you can just delete the question. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: A slight change to your SQL - maybe `SELECT  t2.dDate, (t2.Quantity - t1.Quantity) as QDiff FROM table4 t1 INNER JOIN table4 t2 ON t1.IDPosition = t2.IDPosition WHERE t1.dDate = (SELECT MAX(dDate) FROM table4 WHERE dDate<t2.dDate)` just in case the previous day wasn't yesterday.

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot to check for weekends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self join can be used to do that. It requires the table to have a (PK) ID or an incremental column.

```
select b.IDposition
      ,(b.quantity-a.quantity) as DiffQuantity
      ,(b.price-a.price) as DiffPrice
      , (b.totalprice-a.totalprice) as DiffTotalPrice 
from  table a 
inner join table b on a.ID=b.ID-1
```